# El efecto hover se para cuando paso el cursor sobre una etiqueta p

Tags: html, css

Cuando paso el cursor sobre la etiqueta `<p>` se para la animación y, obviamente, si no paso el cursor sobre la etiqueta `<p>` va todo bien.

¿Cómo podría evitar que cuando pase el cursor sobre la etiqueta `<p>` se detenga el efecto `hover` que tiene la imagen?

Aquí está el código:

```css
.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.card img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.card p {
  position: absolute;
  color: orange;
  top: 40%;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/300/200">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que especificas el selector `:hover` únicamente a la imagen, por lo que al salir de la imagen y entrar en el párrafo (que está sobre la imagen) el selector deja de cumplirse, finalizando el efecto.

Para corregirlo indica que el efecto debe activarse cuando pases sobre el padre (el elemento con clase `card`) pero que el estilo se aplique sobre la imagen:

```
.card:hover img { /* ... */ }
```

Aquí tienes el efecto funcionando correctamente:

```css
.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.card:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.card p {
  position: absolute;
  color: orange;
  top: 40%;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/300/200">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfecta explicación y respuesta +1.

Comment: muchas gracias, ahora si funciona.